# Incremental Achievements in Google Play Games Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, achievements

I want to implement incremental achievement, if I get a score 10 then it should unlock an achievement for that. Likewise I have created achievement for the scores 40 , 100 etc.

I am currently using this method:

```
 if(score == 10)
 {
     PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(
    "Cfjewijawiu_QA", 40, (bool success) => {
        // handle success or failure
     });
 }
```

I have written this in the Update() method. The same way as when the score reaches 40. I am using corresponding achievementid to unlock that.

But my achievement is not getting unlocked. What can be the reason?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There is no reason to voted down this question. I am facing this type of problem so i want to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the method gets called? Could it be that the score goes from 9 to 11 or something like that?

Comment: If i remove condition then also its not getting work.

Comment: Have you implemented `using GooglePlayGames;` and `using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;`?

Comment: Can you post a logfile of when this is happening?  Maybe there is an error in the log.

Comment: Hello guys. it is solved. There was setting related simple achievement on google console. It was not incremental achievement. Thanks.